# Is this how Golang performs multiple assignment?

Tags: assembly, go

A while ago someone asked [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35707222/4532996) about how Golang actually swaps variables in statements like `a, b = b, a`.

To answer, I got out my Golang compiler, put on my thinking cap and crafted [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35707958/4532996) to said question. SO questions are supposed to be self-contained, so here's my answer truncated for brevity:

> To figure out how the compiler makes native code, we need to look at
>   the assembly code it generates, which is turned into machine code by
>   the linker.
>
> I wrote a little Go program to help with this:
>
> ```
> package main     
> import "fmt"
>
> func main() { fmt.Println(myfunction()) }
> func myfunction() []int {
>   a, b := 10, 5
>   b, a = a, b
>   return []int{a, b}
> }
> ```
>
> Using `go tool compile -S > swap.s`, I found these four lines, which correspond to the first
>   two lines of `myfunction` in the Go code: (note this is for my 64-bit
>   machine; the output will differ on other architechtures like 32-bit)
>
> ```
> 0x0028 00040 (swap.go:10) MOVQ    $10, CX         ; var a = 10
> 0x002f 00047 (swap.go:10) MOVQ    $5, AX          ; var b = 5
> 0x0036 00054 (swap.go:11) MOVQ    CX, "".b+16(SP) ; copy a to *b+16
> 0x003b 00059 (swap.go:11) MOVQ    AX, "".a+24(SP) ; copy b to *a+24
> ```
>
> Looking at [the Golang docs on asm](https://golang.org/doc/asm), we can see the assembler uses indirection to juggle the values.
>
> When the program runs, the CPU is smart enough to see what's happening
>   and use a register to avoid overwriting the existing value.
>
> [Here's the full disassembly, if you're
>   interested.](http://pastebin.com/3pH8Bjt7)

My  [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35707222/swap-two-numbers-golang/35707958#comment59091177_35707222), informed by my meager knowledge of (Intel) x86 Assembly, garnered 6 votes and my answer got an accept and 3 votes.

**What are the four lines of Golang assembly *actually doing*?** Was my answer correct?

I ask because the [docs](https://golang.org/doc/asm) I linked to aren't very (at all) exhaustive.

Comment: I'm not sure what that weird-ass syntax is about, but after disassembling it becomes `mov rcx,10 \ mov rax,5 \ mov [rsp+16],rcx \ mov [rsp+24],rax` (which is almost reasonable for 64bit code, but it wastes useless REX.W prefixes on mov-immediates with a tiny immediate)

Comment: @harold It's go asm, not x86

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
a, b := 10, 5
b, a = a, b

0x0028 00040 (swap.go:10) MOVQ    $10, CX         ; CX = 10
0x002f 00047 (swap.go:10) MOVQ    $5, AX          ; AX = 5
0x0036 00054 (swap.go:11) MOVQ    CX, "".b+16(SP) ; b = CX or *(SP+16) = CX
0x003b 00059 (swap.go:11) MOVQ    AX, "".a+24(SP) ; a = AX or *(SP+24) = CX
```

`CX`, `AX`, and `SP` are registers. `a` and `b` are variables on the stack at SP+24 and SP+16 respectively.

Answer (score 3):

It's loading the constants 10 and 5 into CPU registers and then storing registers into the stack locations reserved for the variables `a` and `b`.

It's the equivalent to:

```
 CX := 10
 AX := 5
 b := CX
 a := AX
```

Note a half decent optimizing compiler should optimize this into code that stores the constants directly into the locations on the stack:

```
 b := 10
 a := 5
```

Or better yet eliminates the variables entirely:

```
 return []int{5, 10}
```